# Erroneous use of simple Haskell function

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, typechecking

I'm learning Haskell and there's a lot of type-checking that seems completely nonsensical to me. I have written a simple function to count the number of occurrences of a given element in a given list, as such:

```
-- Count the number of occurrences of an element in a list.
countOcc :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Int
countOcc xs x = length $ filter (== x) xs
```

Now, using this explicitly with calls such as:

```
countOcc "str" 's'
```

This executes fine, and returns correctly. However, this causes an error:

```
countOcc "str" "str"!!0
```

I haven't the foggiest why this should cause an error. "str"!!0 gives 's', a Char, which is exactly the same type passed in the second parameter of the first call.

I'm sure there are some nuances to Haskell's type system that I'm overlooking, or haven't broached yet. Ideally, I'd like to know *why* this is erroneous and furthermore, I'd like to know, according to Haskell's ideology, why it *should* be erroneous.

Comment: Did you try `countOcc "str" ("str"!!0)`? I don't think it is type-related issue, but it's about precedence.

Comment: How embarrassing. I assumed the quotation marks encapsulated the list of Char, so to speak. Thank you.

Comment: It's definitely about precedence. Function application has higher precedence than any operator, so the expression is implicitly parenthesized as `(countOcc "str" "str") !! 0`.

Comment: Side comment: this time the error was easy to spot, but I'd recommend always posting the error message when asking for help. That can greatly help people to understand the issue and then answer.

Comment: Side comment: it is almost never a good idea to use `!!`, which is unsafe, awkward and inefficient. Usually you should better map / fold / traverse / recurse over lists instead of indexing into them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works fine:

```hs
countOcc :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Int
countOcc xs x = length $ filter (== x) xs

main = print $ countOcc "str" ("str"!!0) -- 1
```

As far as I know, function applictaion   has the highest precedence; although `!!` has precedence level of 9, it is still lower than function application.

Comment: Also: `main = print $ countOcc "str" $ "str" !! 0`